# Python: Modifying text file after certain character

Tags: python

I'm doing some operations on a text file with python. But there is one thing I couldn't find a solution yet. I hope someone here can help me.

In that text file in every line I have the word `order` and afterwards a various string consisting of `,` and numbers.

Now I want to delete the word `order` and everything that follows in that line, but I can't find out how. The location in the file where `order` is stated always varies, so I cannot point to a certain location and delete everything afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the accept. I inform you that you can accept AND upvote an answer if you think it deserves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremly easy to do what you want because you only DELETE parts of the text, so you can rewrite in the same file that you read by using the 'r+' mode.

```
with open(filename,'r+') as fr,open(filename,'r+') as fw:
    for line in fr:
        x = line.find('order')
        fw.write(line if x==-1
                 else line[0:x]+'\n' if '\n' in line
                 else line[0:x])
    fw.truncate()
```

If your file isn't too big, so can be entirely read and hold in the RAM, here's another method using a regex:

```
import re

r = re.compile('(.*?)(?:order.*?$|\Z)',
               re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

with open(filename,'r+') as f:
    x = f.read()
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write(''.join(r.findall(x)))
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: Both methods are working fine! Thanks! Can you explain what this code does actually?

Comment: I'm ready to explain points that can't be understood by reading the docs. Did you read the docs on strings method ``find()`` ? Did you read about ``with`` statement ? In first code, it seems to me that the only point that may need some explanation is the fact that ``line[0:x]+'\n'`` is written in the file only if the newline ``\n`` is present in the line: in case the last character of the file isn't ``\n`` and the last line doesn't contain 'order' , writing ``line[0:x]`` instead of ``line[0:x]+'\n'`` for the last line doesn't add a newline that wasn't already present.

Comment: ``'r+'`` is a mode in which a file can be read AND be overwritten. The mode ``'a+"`` is similar but has a peculiarity: each time a writing is done ine a file opened in ``'a+'`` mode, the file's pointer is moved to the end of the file before any writing, it prevents to overwrite data in the file. In your case, you WANT to overwrite, so the mode ``'r+'`` is required.  In your case , it's easy because you only delete characters. When overwrites of variable lengthes are performed in-place in a file, the treatment has to be more subtle and ``seek``, ``tell``, ``truncate`` are needed

Comment: Yea, I read about it and yoou explained exactly what I wanted to know! Thanks very much!

Comment: ``f``,``fr``,``fw`` in the codes are file's pointers , also said file's handlers. We can have a mental representation of them as a kind of stylus that is placed above the physical succession of bits that the file is consisting of. At rest, the stylus is placed between two characters, and if questionned about the position thanks to the ``tell`` method, it will give the position where it is in the file. When a writing or reading is done, the stylus is moving. It can also be moved thanks to the ``seek`` method.

Comment: A very important part of the code is the use of ``truncate``. You will easily understand its role by seeing the consequence of removing it from the codes.

Comment: I can't explain all the background of the regex used in the second code, you must study the docs on the ``re`` module. But I can explain some points of the regex pattern ``'(.*?)(?:order.*?$|\Z)'``. The parentheses around ``.*?`` define a group, that means the matching substring in the analyzed text is catched. What this group is catching is any character (symbolized by the dot AND the re.DOTALL flag) of a substring running from start  to as far as possible before bumping into the substring 'order'.

Comment: When 'order' is encountered by the regex motor the part ``.*?$`` says to it that it must go on until it bumps into what ``$`` means, and this regex symbol means 'end of line or end of text' WHEN  re.MULTILINE flag is defined. So the part ``order.*?$' makes the regex motor running until the end of text or the next position just in front the newline '\n' ending the current line.

Comment: As there is ``?:`` before ``order.*?$``, the substring matching this part isn't catched as a group. After having matched this non catched substring, the regex motor continues matching with ``(.*?)``, and the first character it matches with is the newline ``\n`` in front of which it ahs stopped matching with ``(?:order.*?$)``. - The ``\Z`` symbol that means 'end of string' and only that, not 'end of line too', is placed in the regex pattern as an alternative symbolized by ``|`` for the cases where the word 'order' isn't preent in the whole text

Answer (score 0):

iterate over the file line by line (I assume you are already doing this) then use `string.find`:

```
>>> import string
>>> x = 'helloORDERme'  
>>> string.find(x,"ORDER")
5
>>> x[:string.find(x,"ORDER")]
'hello'
```

or if you really need to know that as well:

```
import string
with open('myfile', 'rU') as f:
  for line in f:
     print line[:string.find(line,"order")]
```

I'll leave writing the updated values back out as an excercise for the asker.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly is that doing? x is defining the text and string.find is looking it up in the text and giving out the location, right? and then?

Comment: x[a:b] takes the slice of 'x' from index 'a' upto but not including 'b'. Leaving out 'a' (i.e. x[:b]) takes the slice from the beginning of 'x' up to 'b'. Therefore in your solution, it is taking the slice from the beginning of 'x' up to index 5 (characters 0,1,2,3,4).

Comment: ok, my file is completely empty after I use this :S. How can I define x when its always varying or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: That code was just an example of how to use string.find. I assumed you'd be able to adapt it to however you were iterating over your file yourself. I've added an example of how to do that.

Comment: I have the answer from eyquem how I can do it, but I am curious to do it also your way. I write the file with:

            f.write(line[:string.find(line,"order")])

The information which I wanted to delete is gone, but if I run it like that all lines are put together and I cannot discriminate between them.

Comment: That's because the `[:]` notation will delete the `\n` at the end of the line as well. You'll need to put that back in.

Comment: @ user2834508 That's why I wrote ``line[0:x]+'\n'`` in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = "hello1OrderABC\nhello2OrderDEF".splitlines()
for line in lines:
  print line[:line.find("Order")]
------
hello1
hello2
```

First line creates a list of lines ['hello1OrderABC', 'hello2OrderDEF']. The rest iterates through this list and prints out everything upto the word "Order".

Comment: Maybe I have to be more specific. The word 'order' is somewhere in the middle of the line, before and afterwards the string is varying...or maybe I have just a mental block right now and should do a lunch break.

Comment: In my example, the word 'Order' is in the middle of the line. eg. line 1 (hello1OrderABC): 'hello1' precedes 'Order' and 'ABC' follows 'Order'. The output is thus everything up to 'Order', which in this case is 'hello1'.